# Create an unsigned short int * variable with a fixed size (without malloc)

Tags: c

i'm implementing a HLS solution for a project, so I can't use malloc functions. At this moment I have this C code:

```
unsigned short int * samples = NULL;
samples = (unsigned short int *)malloc(12*sizeof(unsigned short int));
```

Can I use:

```
unsigned short int * sample[23];
```

to implement it?

Comment: you want an array of pointers, or an array of ints? there is no reason why you cannot declare a static array if you know the max size

Comment: How is this related to [tag:http-live-streaming]?

Comment: `unsigned short int sample[23];`

Comment: @P__J__, you should post that as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices - either declare an array with a fixed size:

```
unsigned short int samples[12];
```

Or if you're using C99 or newer, a VLA (watch out for stack overflows):

```
int n = 12;
unsigned short int samples[n];
```

The latter would more often see `n` as a function parameter:

```
void do_something(int n)
{
   unsigned short int samples[n];

   ...

}
```

Comment: It's not completely true that "C99 or newer" supports VLAs. VLA support is mandatory for C99, but it's an optional feature of C11.

Comment: True; but the "big names" definitely support them.